# How to change or get password for Linux Debian Server in GoogleCloud?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, debian

I'm trying to run script on my Debian-linux SSH Server,but it says ''permission denied'' and ''file not found'' when I use some commands.
The Full Code and commands are below here

I already tried passwd, but I don't know the old pass, because google didn't show me it.I also tried keygentool,but the generated key doesn't work.

```
sudo apt-get -y update 
sudo apt-get install -y ntpdate 
sudo apt-get install -y squid3 apache2-utils 
sudo cp /etc/squid/squid.conf /etc/squid/squid.conf.bak 
sudo bash -c 'cat « EOF > /etc/squid/squid.conf 
http_port 80 
auth_param basic children 5 
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours 
auth_param basic casesensitive off 
acl localhost src 
acl localnet src YOUR IP SERVER
http_access allow localhost 
http_access allow localnet 
http_access deny all 
cache deny all 
forwarded_for delete 
request_header_access Via deny all 
EOF' 
sudo /etc/init.d/squid restart
```

---

These don't work

[image]

```
sudo bash -c 'cat « EOF > /etc/squid/squid.conf
```

> Permission denied

```
http_port 80 
auth_param basic children 5 
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours 
auth_param basic casesensitive off 
acl localhost src 
acl localnet src YOUR IP SERVER
http_access allow localhost 
http_access allow localnet 
http_access deny all 
cache deny all 
forwarded_for delete 
request_header_access Via deny all 
EOF'
```

> All 'not found'

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to root by running the `sudo su -`.

Another solution is to use Startup script.

[startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) is specified through the metadata server.

You can add a startup script to running instances

**1** - From the instance details page, complete the following steps:

**2** - Click the Edit button at the top of the page.

**3** - Under Custom metadata, click Add item.

**4** - Add your startup script using one of the following keys:

`startup-script`: Supply the startup script contents directly with this key.

`startup-script-url`: Supply a Google Cloud Storage URL to the start script file with this key.
If you can not restart the instance to run the startup script, you can Rerunning a Startup Script inside your instance by the below command line:

```
sudo google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup --debug
```